# how to record streaming audio with PHP

Tags: php, audio, stream

Is there an API (PHP???) that I can use to allow users on my site to record streaming live audio that is converted into mp3 file as the audio is streaming?

Comment: Streaming from where to where?

Comment: `fopen` + `fread` + `fwrite`?